# Getting AWS instance id in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, shell-exec

Here Iam trying to print AWS instance ID in laravel blade. Iam already tried with these but always gives empty.

```
{{ shell_exec('ec2-metadata --instance-id | cut -d " " -f 2') }}


{{ exec('ec2-metadata --instance-id | cut -d " " -f 2') }}
 {{ shell_exec('ec2-metadata --instance-id') }} 
{{ exec('ec2-metadata --instance-id') }}
{{ shell_exec('ec2-metadata --instance-id >2 /dev/null cut -d ""') }} 
{{ exec('ec2-metadata --instance-id2 /dev/null cut -d ""') }}
```

How to get AWS instance id in laravel? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm guessing there might be a way to do this using the [AWS PHP SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/index.html). You might be encountering some permissions issues when going via the CLI. Or perhaps you need to first switch to the www-data user and configure the aws CLI ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following statement to get aws instance id

```
{{ shell_exec('ec2-metadata --instance-id 2> /dev/null | cut -d " " -f 2'); }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am already tried that one all so but no output it prints empty.